# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no other subrings than $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no other subrings than $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then $R$ must satisfy that it's a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with respect to addition, closed under multiplication and contains $1$.

I'm trying to show that $R$ must be $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but cannot find why. I've tried some examples like supposing that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but this fails since $1,3 \in \Bbb{Z}_4$, but $1+3 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$, but $4 \notin \mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: **Hint:** Think about what happens when you repeatedly add $1$ to itself.

Comment: It generates $\Bbb Z_n$ so if $\Bbb Z_n$ would have a subring I would get a contradiction since $1$ must be there and I would end up with elements whose sum isn't in the subgroup?

Comment: Yes, essentially. I would not say that you get a contradiction but rather that your argument shows that every subring of $\mathbb Z_n$ is $\mathbb Z_n$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb Z_n$. You only need two properties of $R$ to prove that

- $1\in R$
- $R$ is closed under addition.

That second property should get you far. Applying it to the only element you have, it tells you that $1+1\in R$. Now, try applying the property to some other pair of elements.